# Multiple link dropdown issue in materializecss

Tags: materialize

I am using materialize css 1.0.0-rc.2. I am having issues in dropdown. Same dropdown is linked to navbar and sidenav but only one of them working and next thing is it should come below the navbar or link when hovered or clicked.What should I do please help?
[image: Code can be found here]

Comment: add some code & image displaying problem

Comment: Show us what you did/tried already

Comment: I modified the post.Please have a look.Thanks

Comment: Hi @Sagar, please don't post code as an image, because it makes it really hard to reproduce your problem. Nobody will want to type out your image into code. See here for more information: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303816/3088508

Comment: Please do not provide textual information as image.

Comment: Sorry Guys I am new here! And this is my first question asked so please forgive me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it won't work for same dropdown structure in both `Navbar` and `Sidebar`. Making two dropdown structure can solve your problem.

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger">
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li>
                <a href="sass.html">Sass</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="badges.html">Components</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">Dropdown
                    <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li>
        <a href="#!">one</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#!">two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#!">three</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <li>
        <a href="#!">one</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#!">two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#!">three</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li>
        <a href="sass.html">Sass</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="badges.html">Components</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-trigger2" href="#" data-target="dropdown2">Dropdown
            <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown({
            hover: true
        });
        $(".dropdown-trigger2").dropdown();
        $('.sidenav').sidenav();
    });
</script>
```