# Multiple dropdown trigger not opening dropdown content

Tags: javascript, dropdown, materialize

I have multiple dropdown triggers for the same dropdown-content.

But when the dropdown-content is already opened, when I click on another dropdown-trigger, the dropdown-content doesn't show up. I need to click somewhere else for the dropdown-content appear.

[Click here to see the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiZev.gif) (the red circles is when I clicked)

I am using Materialize v1.0.0-rc.2

**Dropdown Content:**

```
<ul id="user-settings-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a>Tornar Moderador</a></li>
  <li><a>Tornar Mentor</a></li>
  <li><a>Tornar Jogador</a></li>
  <li><a>Tirar Moderador</a></li>
  <li><a>Remover</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Dropdown trigger:**

```
<i class="material-icons dropdown-trigger" data-target="user-settings-dropdown">more_vert</i>
```

Comment: Try making different drop-down content structure for every button.

Comment: In my opinion its better to use a copy of dropdown for each trigger.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52128193/8437974 , check the answer to this question, it is similar to your question.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will create one dropdown-content for each trigger then. But there isn't any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to keep only one dropdown-structure then you can use `hover: true`.

```
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li>
        <a>Tornar Moderador</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Tornar Mentor</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Tornar Jogador</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Tirar Moderador</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Remover</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s3">
            <a href="#!">Dropdown1
                <i class="dropdown-trigger material-icons" data-target="dropdown1">arrow_drop_down</i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col s3">
            <a href="#!">Dropdown2
                <i class="dropdown-trigger material-icons" data-target="dropdown1">arrow_drop_down</i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col s3">
            <a href="#!">Dropdown3
                <i class="dropdown-trigger material-icons" data-target="dropdown1">arrow_drop_down</i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col s3">
            <a href="#!">Dropdown4
                <i class="dropdown-trigger material-icons" data-target="dropdown1">arrow_drop_down</i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown({
            hover: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In mobile view, the dropdown not even opens.